NFT minting cost
I am a bit new to Solana, I was testing with metaplex candymachine. I tried to mint a collection of 3 NFTs on devenet.
those are the final cost that I calculated. Are those considered right? Will the cost be the same for mainnet?
Per NFT Minting Cost: 0.012 SOL
Total Cost for 1000 NFTs: 0.012 SOL * 1000 = 12 SOL
the account I was testing with
https://explorer.solana.com/address/5qEupYA78CmrRHWM529wVDUxWEBMmLAMUrZaXqEJ2FWZ?cluster=devnet

Instead of using classic token metadata nfts you could either use compressed nft or the newer core nft standard.
The asset class you are using currently can not be minted cheaper.
A simple core asset can be minted for .0037 sol. https://developers.metaplex.com/core/tm-differences
The cost of minting compressed nft can be calculated with https://compressed.app
